how can I produce high-quality cinematics in Unity without relying on cinemachine’s dolly tracks?
Using cinemachine's dolly track while creating a cinematic / music video is hard. It takes time and effort to get the camera angles right and the motion of the camera to feel good.
For example, I'm trying to create a cinematic where a large character is fighting helicopters, similar to this scene in Kong Skull Island: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEfLPdI-jxU&t=66s
and I want to have the same type of camera movement (i.e., pretty complex, as there are multiple dynamic objects in the scene flying around and moving fast)
Is there anything better than cinemachine?

What specific criteria should we use to determine whether something is "better" than Cinemachine? What specific aspect of the Cinemachine workflow needs improvement, and in what way, to serve your use case? "It takes time and effort" is likely to remain true of every possible workflow when you're trying to do something as complex as this with an exacting aesthetic target, so there might be no way to make it "easy," just "easier" in specific focused ways. So, what specific aspects should answers focus on?
